# Mysql query, eliminate name having assets less than 10, but still show all the data

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my data that I have, I want to show all names that contain assets > 10, but still showing all assets that < 10.

```
id   name          assets
1   'Mira'           10
2   'Mira'           9
3   'Maulana'        10
4   'Maulana'        5
5   'Fifi'           4
6   'Fifi'           6
```

Goals

```
id   name          assets
1   'Mira'           10
2   'Mira'           9
3   'Maulana'        10
4   'Maulana'        5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses an `EXISTS` clause to check each name for the presence of a record having assets > 10:

```
SELECT id, name, assets
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.name = t1.name AND t2.assets > 10);
```

Another option would be to use aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.assets
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING SUM(assets > 10) > 0
) t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

use exists

```
   select t1.* from table t1
    where exists ( select 1 from table t2 where t1.name=t2.name and t2.assets>10)
```

**note:** it seems to me you need >=10 but your description no like that so i have used >10

Comment: It's ok, thanks for your answer I just need the "Where exist" approach cause I don't know and never use it before..